# Using git-subtree to merge multiple upstream patches

Tags: git, git-subtree

Let's say I have a monorepo where I added a subtree like this:

```
> git subtree add --prefix vendor/odoo https://github.com/odoo/odoo.git 15.0 --squash
git fetch https://github.com/odoo/odoo.git 15.0
From https://github.com/odoo/odoo
 * branch                    15.0       -> FETCH_HEAD
Added dir 'vendor/odoo'
```

Now I want to premerge a PR there. My git muscle memory tells me that the logical way to do it is:

```
> git subtree pull -P vendor/odoo/ https://github.com/odoo/odoo.git refs/pull/82307/head --squash
From https://github.com/odoo/odoo
 * branch                    refs/pull/82307/head -> FETCH_HEAD
Merge made by the 'ort' strategy.
[...]
```

However, that pull reverted many commits that were in the `15.0` branch but were not yet in https://github.com/odoo/odoo/pull/82307 (and probably will never be, because the PR is meant to be merged into `15.0` and not the other way around). The git log shows that:

```
> git log --graph --decorate
*   commit faab88e03651b074f031a15821239e0058f379aa (HEAD -> main)
|\  Merge: 35fa4a52e44 4669930bd67
| | Author: Yajo <Yajo@users.noreply.github.com>
| | Date:   Mon Jan 10 12:23:13 2022 +0100
| | 
| |     Merge commit '4669930bd67c925c9492a04996139e3b94907a2c'
| | 
| * commit 4669930bd67c925c9492a04996139e3b94907a2c
| | Author: Yajo <Yajo@users.noreply.github.com>
| | Date:   Mon Jan 10 12:23:13 2022 +0100
| | 
| |     Squashed 'vendor/odoo/' changes from c7b292f7b86..99794e1b4bc
| |     
| |     99794e1b4bc [FIX] pos_restaurant: distinguish product variants
| |     REVERT: c7b292f7b86 [FIX] payment_authorize: show detailed transaction error messages
| |     REVERT: 04f01c58849 [FIX] website: do not translate code
| |     REVERT: 43f9431e71d [I18N] Update translation terms from Transifex
| |     REVERT: 73a51cd0c70 [FIX] {purchase_}stock, product: base product name on supplier
| |     REVERT: ff7368a4d14 [FIX] payment: hide toaster notification for token deletion error
| |     REVERT: aea3a7ff092 [FIX] l10n_it_edi: for foreign invoices without VAT, we need the country code
| |     REVERT: e281bd0850e [FIX] web: visual separation of search items
| |     REVERT: ddafb7fa5af [FIX] project: show 'View Task' in subtask when same project than parent
| |     REVERT: e3d66913502 [FIX] mrp: backport performance fix
| |     REVERT: 0dae344a345 [FIX] web: Add word-break to kanban_content
| |     REVERT: 22bbf43eba0 [FIX] mrp: Context irrelevant of hidden parameters for stock_mrp
| |     REVERT: 97fd5d0229f [FIX] pos_restaurant: distinguish product variants
| |     REVERT: 9fae154ed7a [FIX] l10n_it_edi_sdicoop: avoid tracebacks when no file, batching
| |     REVERT: 1131f8113d8 [FIX] payment: allow the user to archive the tokens he sees
| |     REVERT: 00965df4be5 [FIX] mail : Remove double signature on invoice email
| |     REVERT: 227a639b34f [FIX] stock_account: fix user group check
| |     REVERT: e6bcc77c58d [FIX] stock: traceability report traceback with productions
| |     REVERT: 2dc556f766f [CLA] Add Corporate Moduon CLA
| |     REVERT: 5fab4027cb1 [FIX] account: soften duplicate ref constrains
| |     REVERT: 9bc197fcf6c [FIX] hr_holidays : allow user to submit past sick days
| |     
| |     git-subtree-dir: vendor/odoo
| |     git-subtree-split: 99794e1b4bc04de147f9b05f576321e995af05a2
| | 
* | commit 35fa4a52e44664a6bdbacea14aa92cff7f1697f9
|\| Merge: da1be735a4c a97c519d635
| | Author: Yajo <Yajo@users.noreply.github.com>
| | Date:   Mon Jan 10 12:22:29 2022 +0100
| | 
| |     Merge commit 'a97c519d63500935afe040a303065c3d45334b49' as 'vendor/odoo'
| | 
| * commit a97c519d63500935afe040a303065c3d45334b49
|   Author: Yajo <Yajo@users.noreply.github.com>
|   Date:   Mon Jan 10 12:22:29 2022 +0100
|   
|       Squashed 'vendor/odoo/' content from commit c7b292f7b86
|       
|       git-subtree-dir: vendor/odoo
|       git-subtree-split: c7b292f7b86679b11527a68093ed70b36dc2fd1a
| 
* commit da1be735a4cc352cd4d1e6055f747abb44d07ae0
  Author: Yajo <Yajo@users.noreply.github.com>
  Date:   Mon Jan 3 13:45:16 2022 +0100
  
      build: bare bones pyproject.toml
```

To my eyes, it behaved more like a `git reset` than like a `git pull`, where changes are usually merged with whatever you have locally.

Why did `git subtree pull` revert those changes? How can I achieve a normal merge instead?